# Redux: how to combine reducer taking asynchronous action with normal reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-reducer

Redux newbie here.

I have an reducer `ProductListReducer` that takes asynchronous action (its action creator fetch data from API), whose initial state is `InitialProductListStates`. I have another synchronous reducer `CartReducer`, whose initial state is `InitialCartListStates`. I want to have them work on one single store `store`. How should I do this?

My attempt: I want to first combine the two reducers into one `reducer` with `combineReducers`, and then combine their initial states as `InitialState = {ProductListReducer: InitialProductListStates, CartReducer:InitialCartListStates}`. Next, I want to use `createStore()`:
`store = createStore(reducer, InitialState , applyMiddleware(thunk));`

However, I am stuck at the first test-of-concept: After combining `ProductListReducer` with itself and setting `InitialState={ProductListReducer: InitialProductListStates}` , I re-run the app and get this error:

```html
Uncaught Error: Minified Redux error #12; visit https://redux.js.org/Errors?code=12 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors. 
    at redux.js:441:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at redux.js:434:25
    at _l.ProductListReducer (redux.js:499:5)
    at main.ts:4:17
    at index.tsx:13:27
    at index.tsx:13:27
```

My codes (that doesn't work):

```js
import reducer from './reducers/main';

import { ProductListReducer, InitialProductListStates } from './reducers/reducers'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const InitialStates = {
    ProductListReducer: InitialProductListStates
};

export const store = createStore(reducer, InitialStates, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

My code (that did work):

```js
import reducer from './reducers/main';

import { ProductListReducer, InitialProductListStates } from './reducers/reducers'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const InitialStates = {
    ProductListReducer: InitialProductListStates
};

export const store = createStore(ProductListReducer, InitialProductListStates, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```